# How to change the if Statement with '?' sign in C

Tags: c

```
void get_out_last_10(thisWay_t *thisWay) {
int i;
for (i = (thisWay->gens - 9 < 1 ? 1 : thisWay->gens - 9); i <= thisWay->gens; i++) {
    printOut(&thisWay->states[i], thisWay->height, thisWay->width);
}}
```

I have this function, I don't understand the sign '?' .
How to change those statements more 'Normally'.. other word make it logic same?

Comment: look up "conditional operator" in your book or reference

Comment: You can also use max(1, thisWay->gens - 9) which gives the same result.

Answer (score 3):

> The operator ?: is used as follows:

```
      condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

> The condition is evaluated true or false as a Boolean expression. On the basis of the evaluation of the Boolean condition, the entire expression returns value_if_true if condition is true, but value_if_false otherwise. Usually the two sub-expressions value_if_true and value_if_false must have the same type, which determines the type of the whole expression. The importance of this type-checking lies in the operator's most common use—in conditional assignment statements. In this usage it appears as an expression on the right side of an assignment statement, as follows:

```
variable = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false .
```

It means if the condition before the ? is true  the operation before the : colon is carried out else the one after is carried out and then the obtained value is assigned to i.So if you were to write it in an if else statement it would be :

```
 if(thisWay->gens-9 < 1)
  {
   i=1;
   }
 else
  {
   i=thisWay->gens - 9;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = (thisWay->gens - 9 < 1 ? 1 : thisWay->gens - 9);
```

If you want to convert it to if else it will be something like this

```
if(thisWay->gens - 9 < 1){
    i = 1;
}
else{
    i = thisWay->gens - 9;
}
```

In this statement

```
i = (thisWay->gens - 9 < 1 ? 1 : thisWay->gens - 9);
```

if the condition `thisWay->gens - 9 < 1` is true it will return `1`
else it will return `thisWay->gens - 9`
And that return value will be assigned to variable `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Question mark (?) along with colon (:) is used to conditional operator. It works  as follows for your case.

```
if(thisWay->gens - 9 < 1)
{
    i=1;
}
else
{
    i=thisWay->gens - 9;
}
```

Comment: you are missing the `< 1` in `if(thisWay->gens - 9)`